# MySQL trigger not firing when supposed from PHP but does from command line

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

I'm implementing a very simple accounting program on PHP + Zend Framework. I have this trigger set up:

```
CREATE TRIGGER consolidate_balance BEFORE INSERT ON balance FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
    IF (NEW.amount IS NOT NULL) THEN 
        UPDATE accounts SET accounts.balance = accounts.balance + NEW.amount WHERE accounts.id = NEW.account_id; 
    END IF;
END
```

My script does only insertions on the `balance` table and selects from the `accounts` table to get the balance.

**The issue**: When PHP executes an INSERT query, the trigger is not fired (or it doesn't work). However, if I copy the query from the MySQL log and paste it in MySQL's command line client, it does work and I get the desired result (the `accounts` table is updated properly). Thoughts?

Just in case, all queries are being handled by an instance of Zend_Db_Table_Row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this issue couldn't be more obvious. Along with the insert to the `balance` table, my script was updating the `accounts` table. Now, this wouldn't be an issue if I were using the `Zend_Db_Table_Row` class as is presented in the framework. But I had it customized long ago to apply a filter to every row in the set, like this (simplified to the matter of this answer):

```
class Mauro_Db_Table_Row extends Zend_Db_Table_Row {
    // Pre-update logic
    function _update() {
        $data = $this->toArray();
        $data = $filters->filter($data);
        $this->setFromArray($data);
    }
}
```

So I changed it to this:

```
class Mauro_Db_Table_Row extends Zend_Db_Table_Row {
    // Pre-update logic
    function _update() {
        $diffData = array_intersect_key($this->_data, $this->_modifiedFields);
        $data = $filters->filter($diffData);
        $this->setFromArray($data);
    }
}
```

Now only the modified fields are filtered `$account->balance` remains untouched.

I also added some column specific [`REVOKE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/revoke.html) statements to the user that my script is using to double the security barrier on such sensitive data :P.